# How do I find the vector $T\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ -10 & -13 \end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I defined a function $T: M^R_{2x2} \rightarrow R_4[x]$ and I defined:

$T\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = x^2$

$T\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} = 3x - 4$

$T\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 4 & 5 \end{pmatrix} = 2x^2 - 7$

How can I find the following function if I know that all three vectors above are linearly independent:

$T\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ -10 & -13 \end{pmatrix} = ?$

What is the method to handle such questions?

Comment: Try using that fact that T(5,0,-10,-13) = -3T(0,2,4,5)+T(1,0,0,2)+2T(2,3,1,0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** You'll need to determine whether there exist $a,b,c$ for which
$$
\pmatrix{5&0\\-10&-13} = 
a\pmatrix{2&3\\1&0} + 
b\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2} + 
c \pmatrix{0&2\\4&5}
$$
and, if such $a,b,c$ exist, find them.

Comment: but those three vectors are not basis so how can I find a linear combination that will match the vector I try to find?

Comment: Just set up a system of equations to solve for $a,b,c$ and you'll find it works. As the other comment indicates, you find $a=2$, $b=1$, $c=-3$. The reason it *can* work is that $\pmatrix{5&0\\-10&3}$ happens to be in the span of the other matrices. If they had asked about a different matrix, it might not have been possible to answer.